# add a new set of data and store into database

Tags: php, database, addition, fieldset

cannot find out what is the problem...for example i want to add 2 row of data...when i press the + button...my data just typed will gone(looks like refresh)...and database will only store the 2nd row of data...1st one will not store. please help me find out the answer. thank you~

```
<?php if($_POST['btnPlus1'])
    $_SESSION['count1'] += 1;
else if($_POST['btnMinus1'])
    $_SESSION['count1'] -= 1;

$AddEducationalQ = "INSERT INTO tbleducational(Id,University,Level,Specialization,Year) VALUES('".$_POST['txtStaffIc']."','".strtoupper($_POST['txtUniversity'])."','".strtoupper($_POST['sLevel'])."','".strtoupper($_POST['txtSpecialization'])."','".$_POST['txtYear']."')";
$AddEducationalResult = mysql_query($AddEducationalQ,$link); ?>


<tr>
    <td>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Educational Background</legend>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php 
                        for($tempfield = 1; $tempfield <= $_SESSION['count1']; ++$tempfield)
                        {?>
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend><?php echo $tempfield ?></legend>
                                    <table width="200" border="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>University</td>
                                            <td>Level</td>
                                            <td>Specialization</td>
                                            <td>Year Graduated</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" name="txtUniversity" id="txtUniversity" /></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <select name="sLevel" id="sLevel">
                                                    <option></option>
                                                    <option>Diploma</option>
                                                    <option>Degree</option>
                                                    <option>Master</option>
                                                    <option>Doctor</option>              
                                                </select>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" name="txtSpecialization" id="txtSpecialization" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" name="txtYear" id="txtYear" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                            </fieldset>       
                            <?php
                        }?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" align="center"><input type="submit" name="btnPlus1" id="btnPlus1" value="+" />    <input type="submit" name="btnMinus1" id="btnMinus1" value="-" /></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
        </fieldset>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I'm missing parts of your code. Where is your form element? Where is the beginning of your first table?

Comment: just simple <form><table><tr></tr></table></form>

Comment: Ye no wonder it's not working.. I'm gonna see if I can work something out

Answer (score 0):

Ok first you'll have to change your form element to:

```
<form method="post" action="filename.php" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

Make sure you change filename.php to the filename of this code.

Now you'll have to make a choice. You can either continue with mysql_*, which is deprecated and extremely insecure! Or you can upgrade your code to [PDO()](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

If you wish to continue with mysql_*, change your PHP part to:

```
if(isset($_POST['txtStaffIc'], $_POST['txtUniversity'], $_POST['sLevel'], $_POST['txtSpecialization'], $_POST['txtYear'])){
    $AddEducationalQ = "INSERT INTO tbleducational(Id,University,Level,Specialization,Year) VALUES('".$_POST['txtStaffIc']."','".strtoupper($_POST['txtUniversity'])."','".strtoupper($_POST['sLevel'])."','".strtoupper($_POST['txtSpecialization'])."','".$_POST['txtYear']."')";

    mysql_query($AddEducationalQ,$link) or die(mysql_error());

    echo "Data succesfully added to database.";
}
```

If you wish to upgrade to [PDO()](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead, change your PHP part to:

```
if(isset($_POST['txtStaffIc'], $_POST['txtUniversity'], $_POST['sLevel'], $_POST['txtSpecialization'], $_POST['txtYear'])){
    $AddEducationalQ = "INSERT INTO tbleducational(Id,University,Level,Specialization,Year) VALUES(':txtStaffIc',':txtUniversity',':sLevel',':txtSpecialization',':txtYear')";
    $prepare = $pdo->prepare($AddEducationalQ);
    $prepare->bindValue(":txtStaffIc",$_POST['txtStaffIc']);
    $prepare->bindValue(":txtUniversity",strtoupper($_POST['txtUniversity']));
    $prepare->bindValue(":sLevel",strtoupper($_POST['sLevel']));
    $prepare->bindValue(":txtSpecialization",strtoupper($_POST['txtSpecialization']));
    $prepare->bindValue(":txtYear",$_POST['txtYear']);

    if($prepare->execute()){
        echo "Data succesfully added to database.";
    } else {
        print_r($prepare->errorInfo());
    }
}
```

Also make sure you change your database connection file to:

```
<?php

$dbhost = ""; //Enter MySQL server host
$dbuser = ""; //Enter MySQL database user
$dbpass = ""; //Enter MySQL database pass
$dbname = ""; //Enter MySQL database name

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=".$dbhost.";dbname=". $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass);

?>
```

On a last note I should add that I didn't see any require database connection file inside your PHP code. I assume you simply didn't post this.

Comment: sorry it cannot work...it only can store 2nd set of data...1st data will not store